# `identify` for `pairs` plot?

Tags: r, plot

Is there an `identify` function for `pairs` plots?
I.e. a function that from clicking into a `pairs` plot returns the row index of the point in the data matrix (data.frame) that corresponds to the point.

I know I can switch to lattice:

```
splom (matrix (rnorm (30), 10))
trellis.focus ()
panel.link.splom ()
## [1] 7
```

However, if there exists a base graphics version, I'd like to know it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an equivalent in the base graphics version of `pairs`, however, the [pairsD3](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pairsD3/) R package provides an interactive pairs plot that displays the row index of an observation in the tooltip when the mouse hovers over it.

An example with the iris data set:

```
install.packages("pairsD3")
require("pairsD3")
pairsD3(iris)
```

More reference [here](http://github.com/garthtarr/pairsD3)